# How to pass selected data from database to view file in Node js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pass selected data from database in Node Js. But i could not able to pass the data to view. Is there any proper way to pass data and display into view in Node Js.

Comment: Where is your codes?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
  var data = fetchFromDataBase();
  res.render('viewName',{data: data});
});
```

in `viewName` (assuming data is string) do

```
block content
  p content is #{data}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: After pass this data to html, how can i print this in html page?

Comment: res.render() function will render the view and display it on your browser

Comment: i understood that but how to display this data in html tag?

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Solution:**
You can pass the data by setting on `res.locals` to the view as below:

```
function(req,res,next){
 res.locals = {
    data : fetchDataFromDatabase() // some function
    };
 res.render('view');
}
```

in view you can access it directly using: 
`data`

e.g. in **Jade**:

```
html
 head
  title helloWorld
 body
  h1 #{data}
```

**Explain:** 
This object contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

> `res.locals` is an object passed to whatever rendering engine your app is using (in this case jade). It is 'global' in the render, so you don't need to prepend anything on to them to use them.

Comment: Thanks Nivesh Let me also try this